# open NavigateUrl window through template field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I try to open  [NavigateUrl Telerik Window](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/contenttemplatevsnavigateurl/defaultcs.aspx) from a button in a grid view which exist in an `update panel` but i fail , it doesn't open the window at all

---

## My .aspx :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="details" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn_details" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/details.png"
          CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>' CommandName="Get_details" />
       </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

   <telerik:RadWindow runat="server" ID="radwin_popupdetails" NavigateUrl="PopUpDetail.aspx"
                Modal="true" InitialBehaviors="Maximize">
   </telerik:RadWindow>
```

---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function openWinNavigateUrl() {
                $find("<%=radwin_popupdetails.ClientID %>").show();
            }
 </script>
```

---

## My .cs :

```
 protected void gv_inbox_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            if (e.CommandName == "Get_details")
            {

                Session["main_code"] = int.Parse(((HiddenField)gv_inbox.Rows[index].Cells[1].FindControl("HDN_MainCode")).Value);

                //System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel2, UpdatePanel2.GetType(), "Open window", "openWinNavigateUrl(); return false;", true);
               RadScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "tabSelectedScript", "openWinNavigateUrl();", true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following resources, they will help you either do it this way, or even improve:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/opening-radwindow-from-the-server.aspx

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window